# Speech API translate to more than 1 language using 1 socket connection and 1 audio input

Tags: api, bing, speech, azure-cognitive-services, bing-speech

I never find an info if it is possible to use Microsoft Translator speech API in a way that one stream/audio is translated into more than 1 language?.

On official docs [page](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/speech-translate.html) I see that I can send only one parameter for **to**=>*Specifies the language to translate the transcribed text into...*

Answer (score 0):

You can't translate into multiple languages at the same time from one audio stream, but you can take the text of the final recognition and then translate that into other languages.

Comment: Hi @Jann, sorry for late response, actually I did solve it in this ways before you answered my question. But my concern is that maybe in this way context is lost, and quality of translation maybe is falling, because to be honest I am not satisfied  with quality